# Locate images and perform instructions in a timely manner

Tags: python-3.5

As you can see in the title there is a game I need to automate using python and I need it to check if 52 images exists these 52 images are the poker cards in a poker game then I need it to save in a dictionnary the flop the rival 1 card and rival 2 card AND I need it to click on the rival which my program deems as winning.

Please tell me Can I do all this in less than 1.5 seconds?
What should I use pyautogui or openCV

Which is faster and more accurate reading the cards text or taking a picture of each card and checking if it exists

Comment: I'm curious what deck you're using. Any time I've ever played poker, there have only been 52 cards. I don't know the answer to your question, but I'm very curious what the other four cards are

Comment: So basically my program will be checking wether 52 images exists then determine its location in order to know if the poker card is inside a flop or rival 1 or rival 2

Comment: It is 52 cards I did a miscalculation